# Path environment variable for C++/Mex/Cuda developer code exceeds Windows limit of 2048

Tags: variables, path, environment

In DOS on Windows 10 using MSVC 2019 Professional

> set
> produces a value for 'Path' environment variable that is so large it exceeds several Windows and looks like multiple copies of paths are repeating.
> regedit "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment\Path" value looks OK, but is ~ 3047 chars. and control panel system advanced environment dialog complains user path is too large to edit.
> Most of the size of 'Path' comes from MSVC paths! which are huge.

Can this issue be worked around by embedding large repeating rootpaths with %variable%. replacements?  Is order then an issue?  Is there a better solution?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.